# How can I convert a number from scientific notation or many places to something like 10M

Tags: java

I have a data feed that sometimes returns numbers like this: 100038 and sometimes like this; 10.43e7. Does anyone have a quick way to turn these numbers into a digestible format like 10M or 100K? Frankly I don't feel like doing the logic myself so I thought I would see if someone else has already done this. It's a pain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try it first by yourself! How do you know it's a pain when you have not even attempted solving it yourself?

Comment: Hint: You can store the suffixes in a `NavigableMap`

Comment: I did try to start, but I know this is something that should be ready to copy and paste..

Comment: No self-respecting developer copies anything except their own code

Comment: So, to sum up: you know _what_ you want and _how_ to do it, but you'd just rather that someone else do it for you?  Please correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Point of correction: `10.43e7` should be converted to `104M` and not `10M`!

Comment: Metric suffixes are case sensitive it should be k not K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch and **learn** if you really care about learning:

```
public class ShortNumberFormatter{

    public static final long MILLION=1000000;
    public static final long THOUSAND=1000;

    public ShortNumberFormatter(){}

    private String format(String stringValue){
        if(stringValue != null){
          try {  
              long l = (long)Double.parseDouble(stringValue.trim());  
              long millions = l/MILLION;
              if(millions>=1){
                 return millions + "M"; 
              }else{
                 long thousands = l/THOUSAND;
                 if(thousands>=1){
                    return thousands + "K";
                 }else{
                    return String.valueOf(l);
                 }
              }
          } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
              return "0";  
          }         
        }
        return "0";
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        ShortNumberFormatter snFormatter = new ShortNumberFormatter();
        System.out.println(snFormatter.format("100038"));
        System.out.println(snFormatter.format("10.43e7"));
        System.out.println(snFormatter.format("123"));
    }

}
```

Happy Coding!